# Angularjs - Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to split the date entered using the text field. I want it in an array.

In html file

```
<%= text_field_tag :checkoutdate, params[:checkoutdate],:placeholder => 'Select Date', :class=>'form-control datepicker input-lg',:required=>true,"ng-model" => "checkoutdate"%>

    <p class='bg-danger' ng-show="isInvalidDate()">Check-out date cannot be lesser than check-in date</p>
```

In Controller js file

```
App.controller('validationController',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.isInvalidDate = function(){
     var checkin = $scope.checkindate.split('-');
     var checkout = $scope.checkoutdate.split('-');

    if($scope.checkin[0]>$scope.checkout[0] || $scope.checkin[1]>$scope.checkout[1]){
        return true;
    }

}
```

and i get the error in console

`Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: When are you running the split?  (my guess is there is no value or an invalid value as the model will become undefined if it is not valid)

Comment: How do i run split after i enter value in input field?

Comment: When do you do the split?  a `$watch`? `ngClick`? or?

Comment: i am new to angular,i have a model for input field called checkoutdate, so i am accessing it in controller and calling the split function. How do i call it after i have selected a date?

Comment: Please provide more code, I am not sure what or how you are doing this without seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into dirty checking when the value is not defined yet.  Simply check to make sure the value is not `undefined` before you run your function.

```
App.controller('validationController', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.isInvalidDate = function () {
                if($scope.checkindate === undefined || $scope.checkoutdate === undefined){
                    return false;
                }
                var checkin = $scope.checkindate.split('-');
                var checkout = $scope.checkoutdate.split('-');

                if ($scope.checkin[0] > $scope.checkout[0] || $scope.checkin[1] > $scope.checkout[1]) {
                    return true;
                }

            }]);
```

Comment: this is working. but array of fields not display to using this code